# Sign of a degree-three polynomial in arbitrary ordered fields

Tags: polynomials, ordered-fields

Let $\mathbb F$ be an ordered field, and let $a,b,q,r\in{\mathbb F}$ with $a \lt b$. Let $f(x)=x^3+qx+r$.

Is it true that if $f(a)>0,f(b)>0$, and the discriminant $\Delta=-4p^3 - 27q^2$ of $f$ is negative, then $f(x)>0$ for any $x\in [a,b]$ ?

This property is true whenever $\mathbb F$ is a subfield of $\mathbb R$, because then we have IVT and the sign of $f'$ gives us the variations of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds in any ordered field.  To prove it, you can pass to the real closure $K$ of $\mathbb{F}$.  Since the discriminant is negative, $f(x)$ has at most one root in any ordered field extending $\mathbb{F}$, and in particular has only one root in $K$.  Moreover, $f(x)\to\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$.  Real-closed fields satisfy the intermediate value theorem for polynomials, and so it follows that $f(x)$ must be positive for every $c\in K$ between $a$ and $b$.  (Alternatively, to use a sledgehammer, real-closed fields are elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ and your question is first-order, so since it holds for $\mathbb{R}$ it holds for any real-closed field.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. How do we know that real-closed fields satisfy the intermediate value theorem for polynomials ?

Comment: Every polynomial factors into linear and quadratic polynomials, and an irreducible quadratic polynomial has the same sign everywhere (since the discriminant must be negative, and so when you complete the square you get either a sum of squares or the negative of a sum of squares).  So the only sign changes can come from linear factors, which clearly satisfy the intermediate value theorem.